# Как обойти защиту элементов массива Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Делаю интернет-магазин в `WP` на `Woocommerce`. Надо получить цену товара. А элементы массива под какой-то защитой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, который я использовал для выведения

```
$product_id = get_the_ID();
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($product);
echo '</pre>';
```

На прошлом проекте таких защит от woocommerce не было.

**Вопрос: что нужно в Woocommerce настроить или какие хаки в php использовать, дабы из этого массива таки можно было извлечь данные?**

Comment: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/wordpress-how-to-removechange-protected-prefix-for-password-protected-posts.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryID = wc_get_product(get_the_ID())->category_ids[0];
$price = wc_get_product(get_the_ID())->price;
```

Вот таким образом я смог получить доступ к нужному свойству.